# How to start debugging in vscode with C# extension?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I recently moved from **Windows 10** to **Ubuntu 22.04** and changed from **Visual Studio** to **Visual Studio Code** accordingly. Installed **.NET SDK** according to official documentation, put all **extensions** on vscode. However, when I press **F5** in *program.cs* absolutely **nothing happens** (when I choose .NET 5+ and .NET Core as running option)...
dotnet --version => 6.0.120
vscode extensions: C#, C# Dev Kit
P.s.: *dotnet run* works perfectly))